Question about upright rod with wheel attached to the bottom that's allowed to fall
Today, Prof. Rhett Allain posted a question and its solution on his TikTok. You can view it here if you are interested:
Question: https://urlebird.com/video/which-stick-will-fall-over-faster-7353691958206057774/
Answer: https://urlebird.com/video/which-stick-will-fall-over-faster-7353694156713135403/
Here's the question. A thin, uniform rod of mass $m$ and length $l$ is held in contact with the ground at an angle $\theta$ from the vertical. Another rod of the same length and mass has a pair of wheels attached to it at one end. This rod is held such that the wheels are in contact with the ground and it makes an angle $\theta$ with the vertical. Both rods are allowed to fall simultaneously. Which rod will hit the ground first?
Prof. Allain shows a demonstration in the second video above and you can see that the rod with the wheels attached to it hits the ground first. However, his theoretical explanation seems to be incomplete. So, I've been trying to model this problem mathematically to find a complete explanation.
Here are the free body diagrams of the two rods:

For the first rod, you have its weight $mg$ acting at the center of mass, and friction $f$ and a normal force $N$ acting at its point of contact with the ground $O_1$. For the second rod, you have the weight $mg$ acting at the center of mass, and a contact force $F$ between the rod and the axle of the wheel and a normal force $N$ acting at its point of contact with the axle of the wheel $O_2$.
I tried to find an expression for the torques and the rates of change of angular momentum in the two cases.
For the first rod, I calculated the torque and angular momentum about the point of contact of the rod with the ground $O_1$ and got the following equation:
$$\frac{mgl}{2}\sin\theta = I \ddot{\theta}$$
Here, I is the moment of inertia of the rod about an axis passing through $O_1$ that is perpendicular to the page.
For the second rod, I tried to calculate the torque and angular momentum about a point $O$ fixed on the horizontal line passing through the center of the wheel. The situation is shown in the diagram below. In the diagram, $r$ is the distance between the point $O$ and the center of mass of the rod, and $x$ is the distance between $O$ and the center of the wheel $O_2$.

I got the following value for the magnitude of the torque:
$$\tau = mg\Bigl(x - \frac{l}{2}\sin\theta\Bigr) - Nx = (mg - N)x - \frac{mgl}{2}\sin\theta$$
Since the center of mass of the rod has a downward acceleration, therefore $mg > N$.
For the angular momentum, I got the following expression:
$$\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times m\vec{v_{CM}} + I_{CM}\dot{\theta}\hat{\otimes}$$
Here, $\vec{v_{CM}}$ is the velocity of the center of mass of the rod and $I_{CM}$ is the moment of inertia of the rod about an axis perpendicular to the page and passing through the center of mass.
Then the rate of change of angular momentum with respect to time would be given by:
$$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \dot{\vec{r}} \times m\vec{v_{CM}} + \vec{r} \times m\vec{a_{CM}} + I_{CM}\ddot{\theta}\hat{\otimes}$$
Here, $\vec{a_{CM}}$ is the acceleration of the center of mass of the rod.
At this point, I don't know how to proceed. I want to compare the values of $\ddot{\theta}$ for the two rods. But I don't know how to calculate $\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}$ for the second rod because I don't know how to calculate $\vec{v_{CM}}$ and $\vec{a_{CM}}$. I would greatly appreciate any help that you can provide me to solve this problem. Thank you!

Although your approach is fine, the problem might more easily be tackled with a conservation of energy approach. I will assume that the mass and moment of inertia of the wheels are small so that they can be neglected and we can simply deal with the stick and the different conditions at the contact with the ground.
Note that after writing most of this I noticed that your $\theta$ is measured from the vertical, whereas my $\theta$ is measured from the horizontal. Sorry if that causes confusion.
First, the potential energy of the stick can be given as,
$$PE=mgh=-mg\frac{L}{2}\left(1-\sin\theta\right)$$
Here I have chosen to take $h$ measured from the center of the stick when it is vertical such that the initial potential energy of the stick is $0$ when it is vertical.
The kinetic energy in both the slipping and non-slipping cases can be written as,
$$KE=\frac{1}{2} m v_{cm}^2+\frac{1}{2} I_{cm} \dot\theta^2$$
So, the difference between the two situations is in the kinematic link between $v_{cm}$ and $\dot\theta$. And it is this link that is necessary for your approach as well. $\textbf{For the case where there is no slip}$ the velocity of the center of mass is,
$$\textbf{v}_{cm}=\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta\textbf{e}_\theta$$
and the acceleration would be,
$$\textbf{a}_{cm}=-\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta^2\textbf{e}_r+\frac{L}{2}\ddot\theta\textbf{e}_\theta$$
For the slipping case, and assuming that we can approximate the contact as frictionless, the insight that is needed is that there are no forces on the stick in the horizontal direction and so linear momentum in the $x$-direction is conserved, which means that the velocity and acceleration of the center of mass of the stick can only be in the vertical direction. We can then write the following relative velocity equation $\textbf{for the case were there is slip}$,
$$\textbf{v}_{cm}=v_{cm}\textbf{j}=v_0\textbf{i}+\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta(-\sin\theta\textbf{i}+\cos\theta\textbf{j})$$
Here, $v_0$ is the horizontal velocity of the bottom point of the stick that is in contact with the ground. Solving for the i and j components gives,
$$v_0=\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta\sin\theta\text{  and  }v_{cm}=\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta\cos\theta$$
We can differentiate the $v_{cm}$ formula to get the acceleration of the center of mass for the slipping case,
$$\textbf{a}_{cm}=a_{cm}\textbf{j}=\left(\frac{L}{2}\ddot\theta\cos\theta-\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta^2\sin\theta \right)\textbf{j}$$
Now we can return to the description of the kinetic energy in terms of $\dot\theta$ for each case.
For the no-slip case,
$$KE=\frac{1}{2} m v_{cm}^2+\frac{1}{2} I_{cm} \dot\theta^2=\frac{1}{6}mL^2\dot\theta^2$$
and for the slipping case,
$$KE=\frac{1}{2} m v_{cm}^2+\frac{1}{2} I_{cm} \dot\theta^2=\left(\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{8}\cos^2\theta\right)mL^2\dot\theta^2$$
Next, to determine the EOM we could take $\frac{d}{dt}\left(KE+PE\right)=0$ and solve the ODE for $\theta(t)$. However, a simpler approach to see that the slipping stick will hit the ground before the non-slipping stick is just to use conservation of energy to see that for any value of $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$, the magnitude of $\dot\theta$ is always larger (or equal) in the slipping case than in the non-slipping case and so the slipping stick will hit the ground first.
Edit: In the comments, the question arose about the assumption of neglecting the wheel. With the energy method above, adding the effects of the wheel can be modified if the wheel is assumed to roll without slipping on the surface and the axle of the wheel is frictionless. In that case the velocity of the wheel is the same as the velocity of the bottom point of the stick, which must now be determined by updating the momentum equation with the momentum of the wheel and the impulse of the frictional force between the ground and the wheel. Kinematics of the bar still gives,
$$\textbf{v}_{cm}=v_0\textbf{i}+\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta(-\sin\theta\textbf{i}+\cos\theta\textbf{j})$$
But the impulse-momentum equation in the $x$-direction now reads,
$$m \left(v_0-\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta\sin\theta\right)+m_{wheel} v_0=\tilde{F}$$
where $\tilde{F}$ is impulse of the frictional force that the ground places on the contact point with the wheel. This impulse is also related to the angular momentum of the wheel as,
$$I_{wheel}\frac{v_0}{R_{wheel}}=-\tilde{F} R_{wheel}$$
These two impulse-momentum equations can now be solved for $v_0$ in terms of $\theta$ and $\dot\theta$ as,
$$v_0=\frac{m}{m+m_{wheel}+I_{wheel}/R_{wheel}^2}\frac{L}{2}\dot\theta\sin\theta$$
The kinetic energy of the wheel is then just $\frac{1}{2} m_{wheel} v_0^2 + \frac{1}{2} I_{wheel} (v_0/R_{wheel})^2$. If we simplify the wheel as a solid disk then $I_{wheel}=\frac{1}{2} m_{wheel} R_{wheel}^2$ and the kinetic energy contribution of the wheel simplifies to $KE_{wheel}=\frac{3}{4} m_{wheel} v_0^2$. The total kinetic energy of the system is now,
$$KE_{total}=KE_{stick}+KE_{wheel}=\frac{1}{2}m\left(v_0^2-v_0L\dot\theta\sin\theta+\frac{L^2}{3}\dot\theta^2\right)+\frac{3}{4} m_{wheel} v_0^2$$
And recall that $v_0$ is given above in terms of $\theta$ and $\dot\theta$.
The next question is whether or not the radius of the wheel is a negligible contribution to the height that the stick falls. If not, then the final angle that the stick falls to to hit the ground is less than zero, and the precise angle depends on the thickness of the stick and where the axle goes through the stick. In any case, if the mass of the wheel gets very large then $v_0\to0$ and the time it takes the rolling stick to fall by a given angle will approach the time it takes the non-slipping stick to fall by the same angle.

Thank you! I have a question about one of the assumptions you have made. In the slipping case, in reality, there would be a horizontal force at the contact point of the rod and the axle of the wheel. So, I'm wondering how good of an approximation the idealized situation is to the actual situation.

The horizontal force that you are talking about will depend on the mass of the wheel. If the mass of the wheel is small, then this force will also be small. You can approximate the force that you are omitting by calculating the acceleration of that end of the stick and multiplying by the mass of the wheel. If you want a full solution then you will have to include the wheel in the analysis.

@russell.price - I added an edit to my answer above to address your question about the mass of the wheel, which accounts for the force it places on the stick. Note that with the energy method approach you don't actually have to identify that internal force.

Sorry, I just got back to this. I got busy. Thank you very much for this! I have a question though. For including the wheel in the analysis, while using conservation of energy, the change in PE should be equated to the change in KE of both the stick and the wheel, right?

Yes, that is correct. The total $KE$ is the sum of the $KE$ for the stick in my original response plus the new $KE_{wheel}$ that I have added in the edit.

Thank you very much!

It's an interesting problem. I had to add an edit to correct my last statement which was wrong. The wheeled case will never fall slower than the sticking case, but if the mass of the wheel gets large then it can approach what the sticking case does.

I'm a little confused now. According to my calculation, the stick with the wheel can fall slower than the non-slipping stick if the mass of the wheel is greater than one third the mass of the stick. You can see my calculation here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zppgbcxdpjbp#fcef6b. I can't put it all here in my comment because of the character limit. So, I'm sharing the link with you. Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?

Ah shoot. Your analysis of the equations is correct, but I forgot to include the momentum of the wheel in the formula for conservation of momentum in the x-direction for the system. This will further modify the equations for the velocity of the bottom of the stick and the wheel. I will post a correction later today.

I have a question about your assumption that momentum is conserved in your edit. I think this assumption is incorrect. There will be friction between the wheel and the ground. Because of this, momentum in the x-direction would not be conserved. Is my understanding correct?

Yes, you are again correct. I am really botching this case. The impulse of the frictional force cannot be neglected, but it can be related to the change in angular momentum of the wheel. This modifies the solution for $v_0$. I have now included this correction as well. I hope this is the last one.
